# parameters and global variables, menu program

Tags: c++, variables, parameters, menu, global

I have a menu driven program and the menu function needs alot of parameters, and I want to be able to call the menu function from other functions so does that mean that every function has to have these many arguments even if they don't need them or is there a better way? The switch is calling other functions which all have the same parameters as the menu one. Here's the code:

```
void menu(int *sklad, int *Max, int *Vrh, int *sklad2, int *Rep, int *Glava){

    int izbira;

    cout << "Sklad - izbira:" << endl;
    cout << "1) Vnos podatka" << endl;
    cout << "2) Branje podatka" << endl;
    cout << "3) Izpis celotnega sklada" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Krozna vrsta - izbirta:" << endl;
    cout << "4) Vnos podatka" << endl;
    cout << "5) Branje podatka" << endl;
    cout << "6) Izpis vrste od glave do repa" << endl << endl;
    cout << "7) Konec" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Izbira: ";

    cin >> izbira;
    if(!cin){
        cout << "Vnesite celo stevilo" << endl;
        menu(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
    }

    switch(izbira){
    case 1: {
        vnosPodatka(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
        break;
    }

    case 2: {
        branjePodatka(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
        break;
    }

    case 3: {
        izpisSklada(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
        break;
    }

    case 4:{
        vnosPodatka2(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
        break;
    }

    case 5: {
        branjePodatka2(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
        break;
    }

    case 6: {
        izpisSklada2(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
        break;
    }

    case 7: {
        break;
    }

    default: {
        cout << "napaka" << endl;
        menu(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have some of your menu function parameters have default arguments.

Comment: Not really, because each function changes these parameters, so if they are set to default, the other function is basically useles, right?

Comment: Don't recurse, use a loop.

Comment: Use a loop for what?

Comment: @Sobočan if every parameter is required to call the function then you can't use default parameters.  But are these really function parameters?  Or are they globals?

Comment: The variables are defined in main

Answer (score 1):

A lambda with captures can help here. I did not propose defaults since I see pointers as parameters, which, I assume, are addresses to the data. 
    void menu(int *sklad, int *Max, int *Vrh, int *sklad2, int *Rep, int *Glava);

```
auto fixedMenu = [&fixedSklad, &fixedMax, &fixedVhr, &fixedsklad2, &fixedRep](int * Glava) { menu(fixed...., Glava); });

fixedMenu(&gLava);
```

You can do lambdas like this with as many fixed parameters as you want that creates another function at your convenience.

I would also suggest to use references for the parameters of the menu function if they cannot be `nullptr` and `const` if they cannot change inside.

Answer (score 0):

C++ being an object oriented program, I suggest making a Menu class. You can make it a singleton, so that other part of your program can modify it.

---

*Menu.h*

```
class Menu {
      Menu(int *_sklad, int *_Max, int *_Vrh,
           int *_sklad2, int *_Rep, int *_Glava)
          : sklad(_sklad), Max(_Max), Vrh(_Vrh),
            sklad2(_sklad2), Rep(_Rep), Glava(_Glava) {}
public:
  int* sklad;
  int* Max;
  int* Vrh;
  int* sklad2;
  int* Rep;
  int* Glava;

  static Menu& sharedInstance();
  void run();
};
```

*Menu.cpp*

---

```
#include <Menu.h>

Menu& sharedInstance() {
   static Menu instance(<default instanciation>);
   return instance;
}

void Menu::run()
{
  int izbira;
  cout << "Sklad - izbira:" << endl;
  cout << "1) Vnos podatka" << endl;
  cout << "2) Branje podatka" << endl;
  cout << "3) Izpis celotnega sklada" << endl << endl;
  cout << "Krozna vrsta - izbirta:" << endl;
  cout << "4) Vnos podatka" << endl;
  cout << "5) Branje podatka" << endl;
  cout << "6) Izpis vrste od glave do repa" << endl << endl;
  cout << "7) Konec" << endl << endl;
  cout << "Izbira: ";

  cin >> izbira;
  if(!cin){
      cout << "Vnesite celo stevilo" << endl;
      menu(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
  }

  switch(izbira){
  case 1: {
    vnosPodatka(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
    break;
  }

  case 2: {
    branjePodatka(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
    break;
  }

  case 3: {
      izpisSklada(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
      break;
  }

  case 4:{
      vnosPodatka2(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
      break;
  }

  case 5: {
      branjePodatka2(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
      break;
  }

  case 6: {
      izpisSklada2(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
      break;
  }

  case 7: {
      break;
  }

  default: {
      cout << "napaka" << endl;
      menu(sklad, Max, Vrh, sklad2, Rep, Glava);
  }
}
```

---

You can then modify your instance as much as you want, and do not need to repeat the all command line.